# Does it make sense to `json.loads` to accept booleans, null and numbers as a JSON string?

Tags: python, json

I ran into this issue while challenging the **Python** `json.loads` method.

As I understand it this method should convert a stringified JSON structure in a:

- Python `dict` while parsing a JSON structured as a map
- Python `list` while parsing a JSON structured as an array

So far these behaviours are okay:

```py
import json
>>> json.loads("{\"hello\": \"world\"}")
{'hello': 'world'}
>>> json.loads("[{\"hello\": \"world\"}]")
[{'hello': 'world'}]
```

And it is also okay to raise an exception when string has nothing to deal with a JSON structure:

```py
>>> json.loads("abc")
...
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But then how is it consistent to convert strings that represent booleans, null and numbers?:

```py
>>> json.loads("true")
True
>>> json.loads("false")
False
>>> json.loads("null") is None
True
>>> json.loads("1")
1
>>> json.loads("1.0")
1.0
```

Comment: `[true, false, null, 1, 1.0]` is a valid JSON array with valid JSON values…?! Why shouldn't those values be valid by themselves? `abc` is *not* valid as anything in JSON.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? JSON is not just about objects and arrays, and `true`, `false`, ... etc are important to represent meaningful values. [A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: Okay I got it. I thought `json.loads` was working at JSON structure level only (map or array). But in reality it works at the value level too. And `abc` can be interpreted as a valid JSON value like so: `json.loads('"abc"')`

Comment: To clear up the most common confusion: Are you aware that JSON is a *notation* (aka text), so that the *notation* for a string is `"abc"` and a Python literal *containing* this text would be `'"abc"'` (note the single quotes around double quotes)?

Comment: I vaguely remember that JSON decoders were supposed to expect an object or array as containing data structure for some reason or another; but in practice virtually no JSON decoder does so, because they need to be implemented recursively anyway, and putting in a restriction to require certain top-level values can actually be more work than to allow any value.

Comment: Small hint: `json.loads("{\"hello\": \"world\"}")` is better readable if you write it as `json.loads('{"hello": "world"}')`

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `json.loads` is a **Python string**, which is usually filled with a value with double quotes to denote it is a **Python string literal**.

In your example of raising an exception, if you mean `"abc"` as a **JSON string**, you should write the code as:

```py
json.loads('"abc"')
```

the inner double quotes is part of content of JSON text, which fits the requirement of JSON string of standard [RFC 7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html).

> how is it consistent to convert strings that represent booleans, null
> and numbers?

Also refer to [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html#section-3):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names:
>
> ```
>   false null true
> ```
>
> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are
> allowed.

So these are allowed while `abc` raises an exception.